# Provide Chart.js with data via AJAX JSON not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I'm building a dashboard and I want to display information from my database directly to Chart.js.

I've created the Ajax and it returns the correct data. I've put this altogether in the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://localhost/cwwa/web/app.php/AJAX/dashboard/",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(json) {

        var ChartData = json.enviFig;

        var oacData = [
            $.each(ChartData, function(i, item) {
                {
                    value: ChartData[i].totalTonne;
                    color: "#F7464A";
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E";
                    label: ChartData[i].wasteType;
                }
            })
        ];

        var rCM = document.getElementById("recycledChartMain").getContext("2d");

        var recycledChartMain = new Chart(rCM).Pie(oacData);

    }

});
```

However, when the page is loaded the graph doesn't appear. Firebug doesn't an error either, only this warning relating to the Chart.js file:

> canvas: an attempt to set strokeStyle or fillStyle to a value that is
>   neither a string, a CanvasGradient, or a CanvasPattern was ignored.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The way you populate oacData doesn't sound right. I would expect this:

```
var oacData = [];
$.each(ChartData, function(i, item) {
    oacData.push(
        {
            value: ChartData[i].totalTonne,
            color: "#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: ChartData[i].wasteType
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: It threw an error, saying it was missing a `}` after `wasteType;` but changing the `;` to a `,` remove this error, so it runs without an error now. However the chart doesn't appear?

Comment: Code corrected, inside an object you should use commas, not semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

Now oacData is objects within an array within an array.
That's why Chart.js can't parse your data.
Just omit the brackets like:

```
var oacData = $.each(ChartData, function(i, item) {
                {
                    value: ChartData[i].totalTonne;
                    color: "#F7464A";
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E";
                    label: ChartData[i].wasteType;
                }
            });
```

And you will have an array with objects.